# can Apache Camel output a jdbc interface instead of Java object maps?

Tags: jdbc, apache-camel, couchdb

Can Apache Camel output a jdbc interface instead of Java object maps?
I need to read from CouchdB AND output standard JDBC query results
I thought I could use Camel as the connector.
It can read CouchDB but apparently can not output standard JDBC objects to a client app.
Is there anyway Camel can output JDBC results? 
I have a tool that needs a JDBC connection and a standard JDBC interface.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the data from the database as a `javax.sql.ResultSet` or what kind of interface do you think about? The camel-couchdb component uses a Couch Java Client and not a JDBC driver, so you cannot do this with Camel.

But you can look at using a JDBC driver for CouchDB and not use Camel at all.

Comment: Yes I want to generate a javax.sql.Result. Use a standard JDBC connector, get standard JDBC metadata etc.
I did look at JDBC driver for CouchDB and could only find an actively supported one for Couchbase. Unfortunately CouchDB is a component in the product so switching to Couchbase is not an option. I can also can't get the reporting tool to use anything other than JDBC input. Thanks for your help